# How do I use classifyAndWriteAnswersKBest in coreNLP pipeline?

Tags: stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

When I used a CRF classifier directly, I could use the classifyAndWriteAnswersKBest function (as below) to calculate a probability score.

```
Counter<List<CoreLabel>> kBest = classifier.classifyKBest(labels, 
CoreAnnotations.AnswerAnnotation.class, 1);
List<List<CoreLabel>> sorted = Counters.toSortedList(kBest);
for (List<CoreLabel> l : sorted) {
  prob_list.add(Math.exp(kBest.getCount(l)));
}
```

But now because I need to take advantage of the POS tag as a feature for my classifier, I called the StanfordCoreNLP API and used ner.model to initiate the classifier. Now the problem is, how can I still use the above Kbest function to do the similar calculation without loading the classifier again?